# What is the difference between "начать и начаться" and "учить и учиться"?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова, глаголы

У меня есть вопрос: <strike>что</strike> *в чём* разница между "начать и начаться" и "учить и учиться"?

What is the difference between "начать и начаться" and "учить и учиться"?

Comment: What does dictionary say?

Comment: @Abakan The dictionaries I was looking at said that the first two both meant "to begin" and that the second two meant "to learn". However, their usage (between the reflexive and non-reflexive) seemed to be different.

Comment: Is it a question about these specific words or about consistent pattern in general?

Comment: @AnatolyRybalchenko Why not both? Ideally the latter, but if not possible, then just the former.

Answer (score 2):

I asked my friend this question a while ago, and she gave a very thorough and thoughtful response, so I thought I would post it here so more people could benefit from it in the future.

> You can't imagine how puzzled I was. So, I had to think really hard about it. =D
>   Ты не представляешь, как меня озадачил. Так что пришлось серьёзно подумать об этом.
>
> Ok. Now, a little bit of grammar introduction (there is nothing new I guess so just roll with it if you know it).
>   Pairs of words 'начать' and 'начаться', and 'учить' и 'учиться' have the same roots and here sometimes close meanings. The most obvious difference is the '-ся' postfix. It shows that the verb is reflexive, so in Russian that means that the object and the subject in the sentence are probably the same, e.g Я одеваюсь - I dress myself, Мы виделись утром - We met (each other) in the morning etc.
>   Thus, when using verbs with a postfix, you usually mean that the subject and object are the same. 
>   Most of grammar stuff is over. 
>   Anyway, Повторение - мать учения*.
>
> As to your pairs of words. 
>   По поводу твоих слов.
>
> Let's start with 'учить' and 'учиться':
>   the general meaning is 'to learn' in most cases.
>
> However, there are some differences. It is better to show by examples.
>   Но есть некоторые различия. Это лучше видно на примерах.
>
> 'Учиться' in most cases means 'to learn how to do something'. Using the word 'учить' with verbs we get the meanig 'to teach'
>
> Учиться танцевать. - Learn to dance.           Учить танцевать - Teach to dance.
>   More about a person:
>   Я учусь танцевать - I learn to dance (kind of by myself).            Я учу танцевать - I teach to dance.
>
> And it's all the same with verbs.
>
> Now more complicated. These words with nouns and pronouns.
>   Сейчас посложнее. Эти же слова с существительными и местоимениями.
>
> The grammatical difference is that after 'учить' goes accusative case and after 'учиться' dative. Frankly speaking, I'm not sure how to systemize the use of them. 
>   Разница в грамматике состоит в том, что после 'учить' нужен винительный падеж, а после 'учиться' дательный. Честно говоря, я не уверена как можно систематизировать их использование.
>
> However, here are some tips.
>   When you need to say that you study at university, school, are taking a course etc. you use 'учиться':
>   Я учусь в университете. Я учусь на курсах. и т.п. 
>   But I study law at university. Я учу юриспруденцию в университете. (The best is 'изучаю', but anyway...)
>
> Also, 'учиться' is similar to the meaning of simple tenses (regularity), and 'учить' besides that can be also used to describe continuous action.
>   Я учусь грамоте. (the same as present simple)     Я учу грамоту. (May be both simple or continuous, it depends on the context.)
>
> Now 'начать' and 'начаться'. I almost wrote a book. 
>   First, we don't use 'начаться' with verbs. At all.
>   Первое, мы не ставим 'начаться' с глаголами. Совсем.
>
> If you need to say I started to read, to sing, to cry etc. you use form of the word 'начать'.
>
> 'Начаться' is more commonly used in impersonal constructions such as 
>   Начался дождь. It started to rain.
>   Началась гроза. A storm began. 
>   Урок начался. The lesson began. 
>   Фильм начался. The film started. 
>   As if something started by itself. Puts more selfness in a sentence. =)
>
> In other cases you probably will use 'начать'. 
>   Oh, as to cases. 'Начаться' needs nominative and 'начать' accusative.
>
> Hope it's more or less helpful,
>   Надеюсь, что это более менее полезно.
>
> *[Repetiljo est inaier studiorum](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/3453/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that "*учить*" and "*начать*" need an object (you can only "*учить*" or "*начать*" something) while "*учиться*" и "*начаться*" do not.

Example:

*Группа начала концерт ровно в 19-00 (The band began the concert exactly at 19-00)*

but

*Концерт начался ровно в 19-00 (The concert began exactly at 19-00)*

It's not so strict with "учиться" and mostly depends on context. "Учиться ездить на велосипеде" means "to learn to ride a bike" while "учить ездить на велосипеде" means "to teach to ride a bike". At the same time "учить математику" is "to learn math" but "учить девочку" is "to teach a girl" :).

Answer (score 0):

the answer is very simple: first verb in each pair is transitive, the second is not, which determines their usage

reflexive verbs are intransitive

Comment: How would this help a beginner, lol?

Comment: the question was about the difference, so i named it, i'm sure Russian grammar books deal with different classes of verbs, and the details are already explained there so it only takes a search by the names of these classes which i did mention, i guess this place is for the difficult bits and/or not illuminated elsewhere, transitive and intransitive verbs is basics